# Correct Ways of Importing Personal Finance Transaction Data

Tags: software, online-tools

I want to transfer my financial data ( years of it!!) from [Buxfer](http://buxfer.com) to yet-to-be-known online personal finance web app. I tried to download my data in both .qif and ofx format.

I tried to import the data into [MoneyStrands](https://money.strands.com/), however, a lot of the columns ( such as tag and category) available in Buxfer are not recognized in MoneyStrands. This is very puzzling as I thought that .qif and .ofx are standard formats and they should be the recognized across different financial services.

Did I do anything wrong? What are the correct ways of importing financial data?

Comment: I was thinking of how to tag this question and I'm not sure what is a good tag for transfering financial data from one app to another?   e.g. Buxfer to MoneyStrands, MS Money to Quicken, Quicken.com to mint, etc.

Comment: @AlexB How about data-transfer or data-import?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to find out in what format MoneyStrands expects the data.  A .qif or an .ofx file may not be the answer.

Comment: I thought a standard file format is all that is needed in order to facilitate date transfer between different service providers? After all, that's what a *standard* is all about, isn't it?

Comment: You're right, but some people choose not to adopt standards.  People aren't obligated to play in the same cage as the 800-pound gorilla (Intuit).